# min-height css is not working in outlook 2007 newsletter

Tags: css, outlook-2007, newsletter

i have made a newsletter in html with inline css and its working fine but when we are seeing it in outlook its not looking good and there are some css missing.its working fine with all other like gmail.

Here is the link for that html template:

http://fashionfad.in/newsletter/april-29/

Answer (score 1):

Outlook is one of the mail services with the poorest support for css styles. [Here](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) you have a list of supported styles in different mail clients. I can't find min-height support, but from what I see, min-width and max-width are also not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Min-height is not supported. Instead set your table cell `height=""` to the minimum and it will stretch larger if needed:

```
<!-- this has height set to 100, but stretches larger vertically -->
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" height="100">
      Table 1<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br><br>

<!-- this has height set to 100, faking "min-height" -->
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" height="100">
      Table 1<br>...
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Alternatively if you are clever with your table nesting, you can fake min-height. This is better when you don't want to set a specific height on your cells, allowing the height to be controlled by the content instead:

```
<!-- this has no "min-height" -->
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
        <tr>
          <td valign="top">
            Table 1<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#999999">
        <tr>
          <td valign="top">
            Table 2<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br><br>

<!-- this fakes "min-height" -->
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
        <tr>
          <td valign="top">
            Table 1<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td valign="top" bgcolor="#999999">
      Table 2<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```